# Why is matmul slower with gfortran compiler optimization turned on?

Tags: optimization, fortran, matrix-multiplication, gfortran

If I use `gfortran (Homebrew GCC 8.2.0)` on my Mac to compile the simple program below without optimization (`-O0`) the call to `matmul` consistently executes in ~90 milliseconds. If I use any optimization (flags `-O1`, `-O2` or `-O3`) the execution time increases to ~250 milliseconds. I've tried using a wide range of different sizes for `inVect` and `matrix` but in all cases the `-O0` option outperforms the other three optimization flags by *at least* a factor of 2.5. If I use smaller matrices with just a few hundred elements but loop over many calls to matmul the performance hit is even worse, close to a factor of 10.

Is there a way I can avoid this behavior? I need to use optimization in some portions of my code but, at the same time, I also would like to perform the matrix multiplication as efficiently as possible.

I compile the file `sandbox.f90` containing the code below with the command `gfortran -ON sandbox.f90`, where `N` is an optimization level 0-3 (no other compiler flags are used). The first value of `outVect` is printed solely to keep the `gfortran` optimization from being clever and skipping the call to `matmul` altogether.

I'm Fortran novice so I apologize in advance if I am missing something obvious here.

```
program main
implicit none
    real :: inVect(20000), matrix(20000,10000), outVect(10000)
    real :: start, finish

    call random_number(inVect)
    call random_number(matrix)
        
    call cpu_time(start)
    outVect = matmul(inVect, matrix)
    call cpu_time(finish)

    print '("Time = ",f10.7," seconds. – First Value = ",f10.4)',finish-start,outVect(1)
end program main
```

Comment: I do not really see a reason here why `-O0` would be faster. However you could try using BLAS for the matrix vector multiplication and check how that performs (`sgemv` or `dgemv` should do it for you). To see what's going on under the hood you might try assembly output (`gfortran -S -o sandbox.asm sandbox.f90 -ON`) and compare them.

Comment: Very strange. This computation should be mainly bounded by your memory bandwidth. Do you use a M1 processor? A virtual machine ?

Comment: The simply answer is gfortran is severely broken with MATMUL (and likely other intrinsic procedures) because of its frontend optimization pass.  I won't regale you with details.  You need to submit a bug report.

Comment: @steve I don't think that gfortran is so broken neither with MATMUL nor with other intrinsic procedures. To my knowledge gfortran is a very well done product. However, as it is close to the machine hardware (in comparison to other languages), sometime the reason behind a given behaviour is not trivial.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I'm using a fairly basic setup (no VMs) on a 2017 MacBook Air (1.8 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5; 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3; macOS Catalina).

Comment: @alexshu98 It seems Noureddine has solved my problem, but I may use your suggestions to dig into this a little more later. I'm still curious as to *why* inlining is causing such a performance hit.

Comment: @Noureddine, I have written a lot of the code that makes up gfortran.  `MATMUL` will give the right answer.  It is broken in the sense that `MATMUL` suffers a horrendous slowdown with optimization, and more importantly, it no longer honors gfortran's `-fexternal-blas` option.  Until the situation is fixed, you can use the `-fno-frontend-optimize` option.  This, of course, disables all other frontend optimizations.

Comment: @steve It is a honor to interact with you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, consider that I may be wrong. I just saw this problem for the first time, and I'm as surprized as you.

I just studied this problem and I understand it as follow. The optimization `-O0`, `O3`, `Ofast` and... are written for most general (frequent) cases. However, in some cases (when `-O3` is less efficient than `-O*<-O3`) the optimization induces a drawback. This is due to the fact that these optimizations call implicitly flags that induce a lower execution time for the specific task. For your case, the `-O3` imposes, amongst other, that all `matmul()` function will be inlined. Such a thing is generally good, but not necessary true for big array or multiple call of this function. Somehow, the cost of inlining `matmul()` is more significant than the gain obtained for an inline function (at least this is how I see it).

To avoid this behavior, I suggest the use of the flag `-O3 -finline-matmul-limit=0` which cancel the inlining of `matmul` function. Using the flag `-O3 -finline-matmul-limit=0` leads to an execution time that is not worst than what is obtained for `-O0`.

You can use `-finline-matmul-limit=n` where you will inline the `matmul` function only if the involved array are smaller than `n`. I use `n=0` for simplicity.

I hope that this help you.

Comment: The ```-finline-matmul-limit=0``` flag seems to solve the problem in all cases I've tested, including the case of looping over many calls to matmul that was causing the largest slowdown. How inlining produced a 10x slow down in such a simple program is a total mystery to me, but I'm very glad to have a solution. Thank you!

Comment: To be honnest, for me too. However, I don't have a better explanation.

Comment: The problem only effects vector-matrix multiplication.  A fix is being prepared.  In an incidence like this issue, it would be prudent to contact gfortran developers directly instead of hoping someone does it for you.  [GCC gfortran list](https://gcc.gnu.org/pipermail/fortran/2021-March/055834.html).

Comment: @steve Thanks for adding that post to the message board. I honestly wasn't completely sure this issue wasn't user error (as I said, I'm a Fortran novice) so I decided to post here first. In the future, I will reach out to the developers directly though.